# Units in a subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$.

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $\zeta_{12}$ be the $12$-th root of unity. Consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$ and the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

Let $u$ be a fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$, then $u\overline{u}=|u|^{2}\in\mathbb{R}$. Are we able to conclude that $u\overline{u}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$?

I was going through some papers and confronted this statement in the proof that $\zeta_{12}-1$ is a fundamental unit in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$. Out of curiousity I tried to figure out why this is true, but can't think of a way how to prove this. (Example 4.11 of the following paper:)

https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/unittheorem.pdf

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the question whether $u\bar{u}$ has unit norm or whether it's a member of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, or both?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I just managed to prove that $\mathbb{R}\cap\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, so the only question that remains is whether it has unit norm.

Comment: I edited Example 4.11 to point out why $\mathbf R \cap \mathbf Q(\zeta_{12}) = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{3})$ and why, for $t$ an integer of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{12})$,  $t\overline{t}$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{3}]$ if and only if $t$ is a unit in the integers of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{12})$. It's analogous to the fact that an algebraic integer in a number field $F$ is a unit in the ring of integers of $F$ if and only if its norm down to $\mathbf Q$ is $\pm 1$ (the units of $\mathbf Z$).